# php xml url's with multiple words

Tags: php, xml, url

having an annoying issue with getting xml data from a url

if i set "$file_show_title" to a single word (comes from the url passed from another page) then all works fine. if if "$file_show_title" is 2 words (tried encoding the url also) then it failed to find the address.

im not the best at explaining but i hope that this is enough for someone to help me please

thanks

```
                $url = file_get_contents("http://www.thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=".$file_show_title);
                $xml = simplexml_load_string($url);

                $seriesid = $xml->Series[0]->seriesid;
                $seriesbanner = $xml->Series[0]->banner;
                $seriesname = $xml->Series[0]->SeriesName;
                $serieslanguage = $xml->Series[0]->language;
                $seriesfist_aired = $xml->Series[0]->FirstAired;
                $seriesoverview = $xml->Series[0]->Overview;


                echo '<img src="/images/'.$seriesbanner.'">'."<br />";
                echo $seriesname."<br />";
                echo $seriesid."<br />";
                echo $serieslanguage."<br />";
                echo $seriesfist_aired."<br />";
                echo $seriesoverview."<br />";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you needed was `urlencode` Please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php for more information

Example

```
$url = file_get_contents("http://www.thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=" . urlencode("Prison Break"));
```

Now Use

```
$url = file_get_contents("http://www.thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=" . urlencode($file_show_title));
```

I hope it helps